# How to select exact tag in regex?

Tags: regex

How to select exact one open and close `<pre>` tag. No other tag inside the `<pre>` tag

http://rubular.com/r/Yk9JqhG8Qz

I want exact match. Only `<pre> </pre>` match  (no other tags)

```
Output I nedd
    Match1:
    <pre>111</pre>
    Match 2:
    <pre>if(a<b)</pre>
    Match 3:
    <pre>if(a>b)</pre>
    Match 4:
    <pre>if(a/b)</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

using rubular and following regex

```
<pre>((?!<\/pre>).)*<\/pre>
```

- `(?!<\/pre>).` matches any character that is not the start of the sequence `</pre>`

but to forbid any tag, just the sequence of one character: `<` can be simplified

```
<pre>[^<]*<\/pre>
```